# git config user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME" is it important to have the name exactly on github username?

Tags: git, github

I don't know where they came from Maruf Hossain but my GitHub config name is `mickeymaruf`, so I want to see my profile picture as well.

So I tried by changing my git config name "`Maruf Hossain`" and "`mickeymaruf`" for two different times and saw that both are working now and only showing my username as geen mark now.

But I'm still confuse how the "`Maruf Hossain`" appeared then yesterday and day before yesterday's commit.
Can anyone explain me what is the issue did happen with it and is it important to have the right config `user.name` or it's just not make any sense?

[image]

i just want to pass this Q

Comment: Note that [`user.name` is typically a human name, not a username](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#user-name).  You don't need to change your `user.name` value to your username, and your typically should not.

Comment: i already did set the username as user.name, so is it will affect me anyway?

Comment: You should change it back to a personal name.  `user.email` is what associates commits to your account.

Comment: I don't wanna mess with it just left :( besides everything's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your commits are associated on [GitHub with your email](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-email-preferences/setting-your-commit-email-address), not the author name.

If you change your local config `user.name` but keep your GitHub email as `user.email`, your commits would still be checked with your GitHub account.

Comment: thanks :) but can you explain by seeing the image why i was getting that full name instead of my github username and also it is not showing my image

Comment: @Märuf It should reflect the commit author name (meaning the value of `user.name` at the time you did `git commit`). Since you mention in the question "changing my `git config iser.name` "`Maruf Hossain`" and "`mickeymaruf`" for two different times", those commits must have been done when `user.name` was  "`Maruf Hossain`".